# How to use tf.datasets with iterator in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use tf.data.TextLineDataset to read from a csv file, shard the dataset over multiple worker nodes and then create an iterator to iterate over them to feed the data in batches. I used the programmer's guide on tf.datasets from TensorFlow (https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets). 
The problem when running the code in a tf session is that I get the following error:

```
*** tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Date,Open,High,Low,Last,Close,Total Trade Quantity,Turnover,close_pct_change_1d,KAMA7-KAMA30,KAMA15-KAMA30,HT_QUAD,TURNOVER,BOP,MFI,MINUS_DI,ROCP,STOCH_SLOWK,NATR,EMA7-EMA30-1d,DX-1d,PPO-1d,NATR-1d,HT_INPHASOR-2d,day_0,day_1,day_2,day_3; No such file or directory
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext_5 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[], [], [], [], [], ..., [], [], [], [], []], output_types=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, ..., DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Iterator_8)]]
```

Now, "Date", "Open", "High" etc. are the columns in the dataset I want to load. Thus, I know that the error is not related to loading the dataset.
When loading the dataset, I use `tf.data.TextLineDataset(file).skip(1)` but according to the error, it does not seem to skip the first line of my dataset (which are the column heads).

Does anybody know where this error comes from? And does anybody have a fix to this?

Please see the following code for clarification:

```
def create_pipeline(bs, nr, ep):

    def _X_parse_csv(file):

        record_defaults=[[0]]*20
        splits = tf.decode_csv(file, record_defaults)
        input = splits 

        return input

    def _y_parse_csv(file):

        record_defaults=[[0]]*20
        splits = tf.decode_csv(file, record_defaults)
        label = splits[0] 

        return label


    # Dataset for input data
    file = tf.gfile.Glob("./NSEOIL.csv")

    num_workers = 1 # for testing; simulate 1 node for sharding below
    task_index = 0

    ds_file = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file)

    ds = ds_file.flat_map(lambda file: (tf.data.TextLineDataset(file).skip(1))) #remove CSV headers
    ds = ds.shard(num_workers, task_index).repeat(ep)
    X_train = ds.map(_X_parse_csv)

    ds = ds_file.flat_map(lambda file: (tf.data.TextLineDataset(file).skip(2))) #remove CSV headers + shift forward 1 day
    ds = ds.shard(num_workers, task_index).repeat(ep)
    y_train = ds.map(_y_parse_csv)

    X_iterator = X_train.make_initializable_iterator()
    y_iterator = y_train.make_initializable_iterator()

    return X_iterator, y_iterator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines seem to be the source of the problem:

```
ds_file = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file)

ds = ds_file.flat_map(lambda file: (tf.data.TextLineDataset(file).skip(1))) #remove CSV headers
```

The first line creates a dataset from the lines of the file (or files) in named in `file`. The second line then creates a dataset for each element  in `ds_file` that treats each element (which is a line of text from `file`) as another filename. The `NotFoundError` you are seeing is raised when the first line of `file`, which appears to be a CSV header, is treated as a filename.

The fix is relatively simple, fortunately, as you can use `Dataset.list_files()` to create a dataset of files matching your glob, and then the `Dataset.flat_map()` will operate on filenames:

```
# Create a dataset of filenames.
ds_file = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("./NSEOIL.csv")

# For each filename in `ds_file`, read the lines from that file (skipping the
# header).
ds = ds_file.flat_map(lambda file: (tf.data.TextLineDataset(file).skip(1)))
```